# how do you get one reputation on stackoverflow?

Tags: support, reputation

I have been getting 1 reputation each day for the past two days. what might be the possible reason for this ? Today when I opened my stack overflow account I found I had got +1 reputation. My account is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2542215/aelor) . I thought that the least possible reputation gain can 
be only 2 and that also after a successful edit of a question.

Comment: Normally means an answer you downvoted was deleted and the -1 refunded.

Comment: I don't see any of this in your profile.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe The rep changes related to downvoting answers aren't shown publicly.

Answer (score 5):

One logical explanation for that would be that you'd downvoted an answer sometime in the past and that downvoted answer was removed today, yielding you that `1` reputation you had lost when you had downvoted the answer.

Comment: yea i think that might be the reason . good answer

Comment: But do you have enough rep to downvote?

Comment: @ToonKrijthe - The [user has 1.8k rep on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2542215/aelor). That' s a lot of reputation to downvote IMO :)

Comment: The account linked to the meta account has only 32.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe The account is linked in the question.

Comment: This is the right answer.

Comment: @AnnaLear how come the OP here did not get association bonus? Bug?

Comment: @ShadowWizard The OP had two accounts that are now merged. The assoc bonus should catch up in a few.

Comment: @AnnaLear I see. Hopefully it won't take 6-8 weeks. :)

Comment: @Anna still no bonus. Sure it's caching?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I never said caching. ;) I'll take a closer look tomorrow.

Comment: @AnnaLear ping. (still no bonus)

Comment: @ShadowWizard ping. (bonus!)

Comment: @AnnaLear awesome! Was there a bug, or just a local specific issue with that account?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Just a random failure as far as I can tell. And yesterday I learned that we have a per-site route to force-grant this bonus. =)

Comment: @AnnaLear you mean you can grant the bonus even for users who don't "deserve" it? Cool! :)

Answer (score 0):

Many combinations of events can cause this. For example, 2 downvotes and one upvote on one of your questions will cause +1 (5-2-2).

[R.J.'s answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228181/how-do-you-get-one-reputation-on-stackoverflow/228183#228183) seems more applicable, though :)

Comment: Answers give +10, questions give +5.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe D'oh! Is it right now?

Comment: @BlueIce - I checked the OP's reputation page and didn't see any such reputation change. And since the 1 reputation regarding the downvotes is not visible to everybody, that seemed to be the logical explanation :)

Comment: @Ɍ.Ɉ Yup, agreed! This is more of a canon answer than one that is applicable now.